# CircuitBreaker immediate fallback

Tags: java, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I followed https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3 for Resilience4J documentation.

I have a problem, my circuitbreaker is immediately connecting to the fallback( on the first invoke) when the primary-backend is not available.

```
@Bean
public CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig() {
    return CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
            .slidingWindowType(CircuitBreakerConfig.SlidingWindowType.COUNT_BASED)
            .slidingWindowSize(5)
            .minimumNumberOfCalls(5)
            .failureRateThreshold(4)
            .build();
}
```

I also tried moving the config to application.yml, but still the same behavior.

```
import io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.annotation.CircuitBreaker;

@CircuitBreaker(name = "backendA", fallbackMethod = "fallbackA")
public String backendA() {
  return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9999/backendA", String.class);
}

public String fallbackA(Exception e) {
    return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/partner", String.class);
}
```

Can someone help?

//UPDATE

More details below.
As shown in the code above, my app is making a call to /backendA, behind a circuit breaker. It is expected that as per config, if backendA is not available, the should fail 5 times and 6th call onwards fallback to /partner API. Or in other words, circuit should open after 5 calls.

This is how I tested.

I started the application. Both backendA and fallbackA are available. After a few calls, I killed backendA. the next call to backendA is falling back to /partner while I expect the next 5 calls to backendA fails without a fallback. Is my expectation correct?

Comment: Can you clarify how you're testing, what you're expecting to happen, and what's actually happening instead?

Comment: @TimMoore updated the question with details you asked for

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I came to know that fallback on intermittent failures is an expected behaviour, though I could not find it documented anywhere. So even if the circuit is CLOSED, fallback will be invoked if the method throws a matching exception.

Note:
If you are not happy with the immediate fallback, wrap it with a RETRY config.

Comment: What you wrote is correct, and it is documented [here](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#fallback-methods): If a fallback method is configured, **every exception** is forwarded to a fallback method executor.

Answer (score 0):

`@CircuitBreaker`- you should expect the result that if it's status is **open** that you will immediately receive a fallback and it no longer calls your desired service.

If you expect the result that when you turn off your called backend service and you want 5 call until you get fallback you need use `@Retry`, if the call fails, then it will try to call your service again.

If you use multiple notations, you can read more about the order [here](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#aspect-order)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, the service was working correctly but it shows the error, for this issue, I used the @Retry like below : (put it on top of your @GetMapping)

```
@Retry(name = "mycircuit", fallbackMethod = "connectionFail")
```

and then define the fallback function like example below : (  Throwable should be there and also the name method should be the same name in fallback, mean "connectionFail")

```
public Posts connectionFail(Throwable throwable){
    return new Posts(); // or any other fallback implementation that returns a valid Posts object
}
```

also you should define this configuration in your application.properties file :

> resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.mycircuit.maxRetryAttempts=3
> resilience4j.retry.instances.mycircuit.waitDuration=1s
> resilience4j.retry.instances.mycircuit.enableExponentialBackoff=true

I hope it helpfull.