# Spring boot Circuit breaker - Resilience4 - Fallback method is getting triggered on 1st failure call itself

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j

I have created a simple circuit breaker pattern using resilence4. The problem I am facing is, fallback method is getting called on 1st hit only.
I am expecting fallback method to be called when at least 3 calls have failed in last 5 calls.

What am I missing in this setup? I feel yaml configs are not being applied.

**My pom.xml**

```
<dependency>

  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>

  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>

</dependency>

<dependency>

   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

   <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>

</dependency>
```

**Service.java**

```
public class Service {

    @Value("${service2.url:http://localhost:6060/service2}")
    String serviceUrl;

    @CircuitBreaker(name = "myCircuitBreaker", fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    public String fetchData() {
        System.out.println(" Making a request to " + serviceUrl + " at :" + LocalDateTime.now());

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate.getForObject(serviceUrl, String.class);
    }

    public String fallback(Exception e) {
        return "fallback value";
    }
}
```

**Contoller.java:**

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getValues() {
        return service.fetchData();
    }
}
```

**application.yml:**

```
 resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    instances:
      myCircuitBreaker:
        registerHealthIndicator: true
        eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
        automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
        failureRateThreshold: 50
        minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
        permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
        slidingWindowSize: 10
        waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
        slidingWindowType: COUNT_BASED


management:
  health:
    circuitbreakers:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your configurations, the following scenario happens:

1. The circuit breaker needs at least 5 calls to calculate the failure rate threshold.
2. If 50% of requests out of 10 (it means 5) are failed, the circuit breaker will be opened.
3. When the circuit breaker is on half-open state, consider sending 3 requests. If 50% of them are failed, the circuit breaker will be switched to open state.

So if you want your fallback method to be called when at least 3 calls have failed in last 5 calls, you should change the value of these two configurations as below:

```
    failureRateThreshold: 60
    slidingWindowSize: 5
```

It means if 60% of the last 5 calls (it means at least 3 request) are failed, the circuit breaker will be opened and the fallback method will be called.

Moreover it is important to know that circuit breaker fallback is triggered even when the circuit is closed (including in the 1st hit). For this point, I refer to these links:

[CircuitBreaker immediate fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69028068/circuitbreaker-immediate-fallback)

https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/1666

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this is expected behaviour of circuitBreaker,

If any exception occured in actual service method then fallback method will be called always.
Only catch is,  Service method will not be called if circuit is in open or half_open state. it will directly call the fallback method in the open or half_open state without calling the actual service method where exception is occuring.